# Where does YouTube store player speed preferences?

Tags: html, cookies, web, youtube, persistence

When I change the playback speed on YouTube it persists through browsing videos. I watched the Network console in chrome and don't see any AJAX requests when I change it. I also looked at `document.cookie` before and after changing the playback speed but it's the same. Same thing is true for `localStorage`.

Where does YouTube store player speed and those preferences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YouTube stores the video speed in [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API), specifically with the key `yt-player-playback-rate`.

You can see this value change in Chrome's Developer Tools by watching the **Application > Storage > Session Storage** screen, as you alter YouTube's video speed.